# Graph with degree at least >= n/2, how adding one more edge makes it Maximal non Hamilton graph(Dirac's theorem proof for Hamilton graph)

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the following part of proof for Dirac's theorem:

**Theorem** (Dirac’s Theorem 1952) If G is a simple graph with n vertices
where n>=3 and d(v)>=n/2 for every vertex v of G, then G is Hamiltonian.

**Proof:***We suppose that the result is not true. So, the graph G is Non-Hamiltonian.
Then for some value of n>=3; there is a non-Hamitonian graph in which every
vertex has degree at least n/2: Any proper spanning supergraph also has every
vertex with degree at least n/2 because any proper spanning supergraph can be
obtained by introducing more edges in G. **Thus, there will be a Maximal Non-
Hamiltonian graph of G with n vertices and d(v)=n/2** for every vertex v in G. But
the graph G cannot be complete, since if G is complete graph Kn then it would be a
Hamiltonian graph (for n>=3). Therefore, there are two nonadjacent vertices u and v in G. Let G + uv be the supergraph of G obtained by introducing an edge uv:
Then, **since G is Maximal Non-Hamiltonian graph**, **G + uv must be a Hamiltonian
graph** .... ....*

Book : "Graph Theory with Algorithms and its Application" by Shantanu Saha Ray

I don't get it how all in a sudden author says **"since G is Maximal Non-Hamiltonian graph"**. In any case author is missing something please explain or point a link to the proof of dirac's theorem.

Comment: hmmm, looks like it has to do something with Ore's theorem

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirac%27s_Theorem. Looks fine to me.

Comment: Although I would like to get a clarification over on author Mr. Ray way of proof.

Comment: A possible correction @ proofwiki : "Since all the vertices adjacent to pk and pk itself also lie on P, the path must have at least deg(p1)+deg(pk)+1≥n+1 vertices" => the path must have at least deg(p1)+deg(pk) + 2 + 1 i.e >= n + 3 vertices. Don't know how I can post it there